# Annotation processor for JMH is not working. How can I investigate the reason?

Tags: java, maven, jmh

I recently joined the company and need to add jmh tests. I created a test project and add simple jmh test there, it runs. But when I move my test, dependencies and `maven-shade-plugin` to my work project - jhm tests are not visible as the tests.
I've noticed that no classed generated under `target/generated-source/annotations` what is vital for jmh.

What should be my steps to investigate the issue? I've also noticed that there are other annotation processing libraries is used. I wonder if that can be the reason of some conflict.

Comment: try to run mvn -X and inspect the output

Comment: Haven't found anything about annotation preprocessors there. Nothing suspicious, Anyway, what should I pay attention to?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution:
My project has `annotationProcessorPaths` inside `maven-compiler-plugin`. So any new preprocessor should be added to this path

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it's done:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <!-- WORKAROUND: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-369 -->
      <path>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
        <version>${jmh.version}</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```